# Redis GETSET - "Returns an error when key exists but does not hold a string value."

Tags: redis

According to redis [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/getset) **GETSET** command `Returns an error when key exists but does not hold a string value`. What does it actually mean? I made **GETSET** for empty value but it just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means if you try to `GETSET` a key holding a value of other types, e.g. `HASH`, `SET`, `LIST`, you'll get an error.